# How to split a string column based on '/' in sqlserver 2005?

Tags: split, multiple-columns, nvarchar

Hi

I don't know how to split a dd/mm/yyyy column into dd as Col1, mm as Col2, yyyy as Col3. It is a string Field, so I can't use Select Convert() query.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this as helpful when I was doing a similar thing a few days ago:
[T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/tsql-split-string)

Just play around with that code and you will get your solution!

Cheers!